# Seq.generate not defined - Is this deprecated?

Tags: f#, sequence

I'm trying to test some F# code from the Beginning  F# book but am getting 'not defined' error with the reference to 'Seq.generate'. (I'm using VS2010 - so this may have worked with earlier vn of VS/F#)

FWIW I've also installed the F# Powerpack dll, but that does not seem to make a difference.

Is there a workaround/alternative here?

```
/// execute a command using the Seq.generate
let execCommand (connName: string) (cmdString: string) =
    Seq.generate
        // This function gets called to open a connection and create a reader
        (fun () -> openConnectionReader connName cmdString)
        // This function gets called to read a single item in
        // the enumerable for a reader/connection pair
        (fun reader -> readOneRow(reader))
        (fun reader -> reader.Dispose())
```

Comment: Good formatting is your friend

Comment: as a side note, you can reduce the line (fun reader -> readOneRow(reader)) to just readOneRow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*generate* can be found in FSharp.PowerPack.Compatibility:[Compat.Seq.fs](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54799#684960)

Comment: FWIW I've added a ref to that in my code and have loaded the module (#r #r "FSharp.PowerPack.Compatability.dll"), but still cannot get a valid reference to the Seq.generate method/fn - am I missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely use `Seq.generate` from the F# PowerPack (either by referencing it, or more easily just by copying it from the source). I think that the function was removed because you can now handle disposal of objects using the `use` keyword.

Writing this using the `readOneRow` function would require using mutable state, but you can probably rewrite it by using something like this:

```
/// execute a command using the Seq.generate
let execCommand (connName: string) (cmdString: string) =
  seq { use reader = openConnectionReader connName cmdString
        while reader.ReadNext() do 
            // Read some information from the reader (as done in 'readOneRow')
            let a = reader.GetInt32(0) // (e.g. ..or something like that)
            yield a  // generate next element of the sequence
      }
```

The `use` keyword properly disposes of the reader, so that's done automatically for you. The `Seq.generate` function is quite nice, but I think that writing the same thing explicitly is probably more readable most of the time. (Especially if you're not using `readOneRow` anywhere else).

Comment: Isn't `Seq.unfold` in FSharp.Core?

Comment: @ildjarn: Oops, it should have been `Seq.generate` - thanks for the correction! (`Seq.unfold` is a different function, which could be used too, but doesn't fit too nicely)